# Statistics version of "What is..." columns in Notices

Tags: references

Each issue of the AMS monthly magazine *Notices* contains a "What is..." column. This column is an expository article on a given topic, e.g. "What is...Noncommutative Topology". Do statisticians have something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days you often find such stuff in blogs! Here are two favourites of mine:

andrewgelman.com

normaldeviate.wordpress.com/